# How can I prevent i2c-designware blocking Ubuntu GNOME on a Dell Inspiron 15 3552?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, dell, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3 on a Dell Inspiron 15 3552 recently. This laptop came with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed; so it should be compatible with Ubuntu in general.

When running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3 for a while, the system stops responding to the mouse, a bit later it stops responding to the keyboard, and finally it starts emitting the following kernel message repeatedly forever:

```
i2c-designware 808622ci00 i2c-dw-handle-tx-abort lost arbitration
```

Other kernel messages are emitted before this, but because of fast scrolling I was unable to read them.

What is the reason for this behavior and how can I stop the system to lock up this way?

Comment: Cross-posting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409788/how-can-i-prevent-i2c-designware-blocking-ubuntu-gnome-on-a-dell-inspiron-15-355

Comment: Is this a problem? Nobody has answered on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, and the question is related to a Ubuntu variant.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: The say that “each site is focused on a specific topic area”. This is not quite true. “Unix & Linux” is not very specific and “Ubunti” is clearly a subset of “Unix & Linux”. Furthermore they say that “SE is not a wild west for questions; a question needs to be worked on to be worthy, and if worthy, it will target a specific audience”. Any yes, I apply a lot of care when writing my questions, apparently much more care than many other people. In this light, it does not feel nice being accused of not doing this just because I have dared to ask the same question on two Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: But what can I do? I am not running this site, and so I have to submit to this site’s policies, even when having been treated unfairly. I will go and delete the question on “Unix & Linux Stack Exchange”.

Comment: did you find any fix for that ?

Comment: The only fix I found was to manually remove a certain kernel module after every startup, before the described problem would show up again. Removing this kernel module sometimes disabled the touchpad, sometimes not. Currently, I don’t know which kernel module is the one to remove. I’d have to ask my daughter about that (it’s about her computer).